# The difference of the product of the 2 numbers you get from the user and the sum of x, y, z (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, difference

```
x,y,z = 2,5,10

number1 = int(input(""))

number2 = int(input(""))

Multiplication of numbers =  int(number1) * int(number2)

print("Multiplication of numbers: " + str(Multiplication of numbers))

x_y_z = int(x) + int(y) + int(z)

x_y_z_toplam_ = int(Multiplication of numbers) + int(x_y_z)

print(x_y_z_toplam_ )

farkı = int(x_y_z_toplam_ ) - int(x_y_z_toplam)

print(farkı)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details ? What is your problem ?

Comment: You don't need to write `int(number1)`, you already converted it to `int` when read the input.

Comment: You can't have spaces in a variable name. `Multiplication of numbers` should be `multiplication_of_numbers` (or something shorter).

Comment: @Barmar now it is saying "Traceback (most recent call last): File "./prog.py", line 3, in EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Comment: You probably have unbalanced parentheses after removing the `int()`

Comment: @Barmar I solved the problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaned and explained version:

```
x,y,z = 2,5,10

number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))  # input prompt message

number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))

multiplication_of_numbers =  number1 * number2  # variable name cannot be with spaces, also no need to convert an already int type to an int

print("Multiplication of numbers: {}".format(multiplication_of_numbers))

x_y_z = x + y + z

x_y_z_toplam = multiplication_of_numbers + x_y_z

print(x_y_z_toplam)

farkı = x_y_z_toplam - x_y_z_toplam

print(farkı)
```